# Looking for cloud storage that does not sync

Tags: cloud-storage, cloud

I'm looking for recommendations for a cloud storage solution for Mac OS, that does not sync.

I need it to effectively behave like an external drive, that I can mount on my desktop ideally, and that I can drag files to manually, so that they are copied rather than moved. I don't want any automatic or scheduled syncing or backups.

Suggestions appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Are you looking for software to run your own cloud storage – or for a cloud storage provider offering you storage space?

Comment: Hi Izzy. Apologies if I wasn't clear; it's the latter that we require.

Comment: Isn't sync a feature you don't have to use, on nearly all storage providers? Use the web interface and don't install the client. For example, while I wouldn't use Dropbox, you could drag files through the browser interface and use the storage, while not installing the client, which means you don't have to sync.

Comment: @JasonK I'm afraid then you're in the wrong place with your question: this site is about software, not hosting providers (see: [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)) – and your qustion then is rather about a "file hosting provider". If it's mostly about cross-device availability: maybe software to self-host would be acceptable? I have e.g. a Pi set up for that. Runs 24/7 at just 2.5W with an SSD, so about 100 bucks one-time for hardware and free software to run the service.

Answer (score 1):

I work for [ExaVault](https://www.exavault.com/) and we offer cloud-based Software as a Service (SaaS). With an ExaVault account, you have have cloud-based storage that can be accessed in a number of ways: directly through a web browser, using an FTP Client like FileZilla, using an API or directly through custom scripting.

When connecting through the web browser or using FTP clients, you will have the option to drag and drop your data directly into your storage. In addition, you can [integrate with tools like WebDrive](https://www.exavault.com/docs/ftp-clients/webdrive/00-introduction) to have a mounted drive on  your local machine for updating the server.